# How to change IntelliJ 12 reformat behavior for enums?

Tags: java, enums, intellij-idea, autoformatting

IntelliJ's reformat code option (ctrl+alt+l) adds an extra lines to enum declarations. It will change this:

```java
public enum Day {MON, TUE, FRI};
```

to this:

```java
public enum Day {MON, TUE, FRI}

;
```

How do I change the behavior of the reformat to not add the extra white space? I was not able to find enums in the Code  style settings (`File -> Settings -> Code Styles -> Java`).

***Update:** It turns out that IntelliJ is treating the enum and the semicolon as two separate statements, which apparently they are because the semicolon is not required for enum declaration. IntelliJ is adding a blank line after a class declaration (enum) and then showing the semicolon. Removing the semicolon solves my problem.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't it also give you a warning saying that semicolon is unnecessary?  It does for me. If you remove the semicolon is that a solution to your problem?  It won't create unnecessary whitespace that way.

Answer (score 11):

Find a tab called `Code Style -> java -> 'Wrapping and Braces'` .
In the list there is latest element called `'Enum constants'`

[image]